# Open div button not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, forms

I have a signup form div which should open on a button click. It is set to `display: none` by default on page load. On a failed form submit, I have this code in my JS file (which works, I tested with a `display: inline-block` setting by default):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)>0){ 
    ?>
    $   ('#home-sign-up-box').show();
    <?php 
        }elseif(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)==0){ 
    ?>
        $('#home-sign-up-box').hide();
    <?php 
        }else{
    ?>
        $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
});
```

I also have this code which ***should*** show the div (it worked before I added the code above):

```
// Log in and sign up buttons
$("#log-in-button").click(function() {
    $("#home-log-in-box").show();
    $("#home-log-in-box").animate({
        "opacity":1
    }, 115);
    $(".body-darken").show();
    $(".body-darken").animate({
        "opacity":0.5
    }, 115);
});

$(".body-darken").click(function() {
    $("#home-log-in-box").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $("#home-log-in-box").hide();
    $("#home-sign-up-box").hide();
    $(".body-darken").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $(".body-darken").hide();
});

$("#home-log-in-close").click(function() {
    $("#home-log-in-box").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $("#home-log-in-box").hide();
    $(".body-darken").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $(".body-darken").hide();
});

$("#sign-up-button").click(function() {
    $("#home-sign-up-box").show();
    $("#home-sign-up-box").animate({
        "opacity":1
    }, 115);
    $(".body-darken").show();
    $(".body-darken").animate({
        "opacity":0.5
    }, 115);
});

$("#home-sign-up-close").click(function() {
    $("#home-sign-up-box").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $("#home-sign-up-box").hide();
    $(".body-darken").animate({
        "opacity":0
    }, 115);
    $(".body-darken").hide();
});
```

They are both in the same file, in the order shown. Thanks so much! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you're injecting PHP into JS here

Comment: I'm new to web development, is it a bad idea to do that? thanks!

Comment: it is bad practice. I'd look into using ajax for this. I can't see how that would possibly work if that is a `.js` file and if it's a `.php` file, then you'd need to constantly go in and out of JS/PHP tags.

Comment: Do one thing take your sign up error value in php session. Me had the same problem.
Like $_SESSION['signUpError'] = 1;//if signup error occurs.

Now in document ready function make a global variable
var myGlobalSignUp = '';
in document ready function fill this variable through php session variable
Check either isset condition and value is one then show your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Russell C.

The most important point is that your js file is parsed by the browser, not the server, and the browser knows nothing about php, let alone $_POST. You can only include static js in the .js files you include.If you need to write "dynamic" js, based on php variables, then you have to include it in the header section of your page, not in a static js file. I would do something like the following. The php decides which if the three js lines is included:

```
    <?php 
    $html   =  "<head>\n";
    $html  .=  ...
    $html  .=  "<script>\n";
    $html  .=  "    $(document).ready(function(){\n";

    if(isset( $_POST['signUp'] ) && count($errors)>0) {
        $html  .= "        $('#home-sign-up-box').show();\n";
    }elseif(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)==0){ 
        $html  .= "        $('#home-sign-up-box').hide();\n";
    }else{
        $html  .= "        $('#home-sign-up-box').show();\n";
    };

    $html  .= "    })\n";
    $html  .= "</script>;\n";
    $html  .=  ...
    $html  .=  "</head>\n";
    $html  .=  "<body>\n";
    $html  .=  ...
    ...
    echo $html;
```

My guess about why your page stopped working is that the browser hit all that php stuff in your js file and abandoned ship.

Good luck